# Does a session variable($_SESSION) require any type of sanitiziation

Tags: php, session, user-experience

I've got a register form which works without issues, but recently it has been pointed out to me that it's a bad habit for UX , for example, if an account already exists, and I redirect the user back to the registration page, without re-populating the form he filled and only display an error message.

So I quickly figured out a nice way to fix this, if after the initial registration data checks out and an account with the respective e-mail already exists, I could just create a $_SESSION storing the $_POST data, and destroy it after re-populating the user's form.

Now my question is: are $_SESSION variables vulnerable to any type of attack, or I can go ahead and store the raw input data inside the $_SESSION, and escape it with htmlspecialchars() when re-populating the form ?

Comment: you could always use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for some basic sanitization

Comment: Worth noting that `$_SESSION` vars are usually saved on disk and of course vulnerable to incorrectly set permissions. So it's probably a good idea not to remember any sensitive info like passwords. Don't directly do `$_SESSION["foo"] = $_POST;` since you risk having arbitrarily huge session files/variables from malicious users.

Comment: @Anonymous.X There's no need to do that until you store them in the database. Using that function for anything else is outside of its intended purpose.

Comment: @KevinMark, I actually meant I will only store certain elements of the $_POST data, not willing to go with `$_SESSION['foo'] = $_POST;`, as you said, I don't want to save any sensitive informations in sessions.

Comment: @KevinMark but i read it in a blog that using this is a good practice when ever it is concerned with variables that have values from the user like `$_POST,$_GET,$_SESSION`

Comment: @Anonymous.X It's always good practice to sanitize your data but `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is only the proper way to sanitize data that will be directly added to a  MySQL query. It's not correct to use that function to sanitize for anything else including HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables in session are not vulnerable to attacks within the session. However, using those variables in other places may open up holes. For example, just because you put a get/post variable in session doesn't mean that it magically can be used directly in a query. It could still cause SQL injection issues. When considering stuff like this, you have to think about where the data originated. If it *started* from some sort of user input, consider it dirty.

The only place this might be a problem is if the data sent is really large and you are just blindly assigning `$_SESSION['POST'] = $_POST;`. There shouldn't be an issue with overflow or stuff like that. The problem will be more that php has to unserialize the data at the start of a request and reserialize at the end (typically only if a change has happened). This unserialize/serialize takes time (it may be quick, but still). I would suggest just assigning only the values you want to save.

Comment: I'm filtering the data before storing it in the session as I don't want to repopulate a list with data that won't pass the validation upon form submission.

Also, I'm using prepared statements and I'm aware of how to protect my database, this was just a little addition for the UX as I stated in the question.

As of assigining, I will only assign certain $_POST data values, not the entire $_POST array.

Comment: Then it shouldn't be an issue as long as you do stuff like `htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES)` when spitting it back into an input element. Wouldn't want someone to submit a form with something like `"><script...>"` in an input and have an echo'd input end up like `<input type="text" name="whatever" value=""><script...>">`

Comment: @ShowTime Even if you assign only parts of the $_POST it can still be quite large. Perhaps try limiting the length of any particular variable. Remember that `$_POST` values can also be PHP arrays if the input is formatted in such a way by the user. See the php.ini `max_input_vars`, `max_input_nesting_level`, and `post_max_size` options.

Comment: I'm only storing things in the $_SESSION after filtering them and making sure they are valid, so there's no way something 'bad' can really get stored in the session.,

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say exactly. But I am about 100% sure the answer is no they aren't really vulnerable. That is assuming that you can destroy the session almost immediately. In this case you would create the session, redirect the user back to the old page, check for session vars, set the vars in the correct location (which you could just do with plain text in this case) and then destroy session. The session would only be alive for about 10seconds.. a minute max? and noone would really have enough time to pull from the server. If they are listening to traffic already you are in more trouble this.

Had to move to answer because that was too long...

You may be able to do a check for user name with ajax BEFORE they ever submit however. That would be better. Don't allow them to submit if the email is already existent. Just submit based off `keyup` or something.

Comment: Indeed, the AJAX method is worth taking in consideration, but I was also aiming to improve the experience for people without JavaScript support, which is why I wanted an alternative that satisfies both classes of users: the JS and the non-JS ones.

Also, as soon as I re-populated the list, I will have the session unset().

Comment: In that case do both. You should never exclude Javascript or another library because the user doesn't want it. Yes catch those who do that, but have that extra security for the ones who do have the support as they will appreciate it much more. (Most likely would be less confusing.)

Answer (score 1):

No, session variables are stored on the server through a variety of options such as saved to disk, shared through a redis or memcached store, and so on.

Even if this data were to be compromised I don't really see how sanitation would protect anything or mitigate the negative effects of such an attack.

If you really are worried about such a thing, you can destroy the temp session variable after you're done using it.